# How can I get the names of annotated method parameters in an Annotation Processor in Java 11

Tags: java, annotation-processing

In Java 8, I used to be able to do

```
 Symbol.MethodSymbol annotatedMethod = (Symbol.MethodSymbol) annotatedElement;
```

and then

```
annotatedMethod.params
```

And I would get both the types of the method's parameters, AND the names of the parameters in the method declaration.

Now that import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol is internal in Java 11, I can get the parameters' types by using:

```
ExecutableType executableType = (ExecutableType)annotatedElement.asType();
            List<? extends TypeMirror> parameters = executableType.getParameterTypes();
```

But how can I get the parameters' names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecutableType` is a part of the "Mirror API", which is generally about types. For inspecting elements, use the "Element API".

In your case, parameter is modeled by `javax.lang.model.element.VariableElement`, and the name can be obtained with `element.getSimpleName()`.

I guess, `annotatedElement` in your code is an `ExecutableElement`. If so, parameters' elements can be obtained via `annotatedElement.getParameters()`.

Comment: Prefect.  I just had to cast annotatedElement to ExecutableElement and call getParameters()